# Is it possible to create multiple SVN Repositories?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to create multiple SVN repository as i have been facing many problems from past few days.

Let me explain what i want.

I have one main repo in my compnay somewhere.
i have a checkout copy of that repo, so i can work on that and make changes and commit to main repo.
Now i would like to have one NEW repo on my local system containing all of that main repo files, so when i commit, it should update all repo, i.e. main repo and the local repo that i have created.

BUT when i try to commit it, it does not give me any options to commit it to the local repo. i dont know if it is possible or not.

I am using TortoiseSVN, Windows 7. IDE: VS2010

I have googled it with no luck.

thanks

====================
EDIT

Would like to have

1st branch (main repo)
2nd branch (local working copy)
3rd branch (local repo, which is depending on local working copy)

so when, i make changes to 2nd branch, it should update 1st branch which is main repo as well as 3rd branch on my local PC

Comment: It sounds vaguely like you really want to be using a DVCS like git or mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

You cant commit the same code to two repos unless you have the same code checked out from both repos. What you could do is set up mirroring, but normally you only do that for a one way relationship (one repo is read-only and mirrors the repo you commit to). If you google for `svn mirror setup` youll see a number of results about setting this up.

That said it sounds like you might be better off with Git where normally you always commit to a local copy of the repository and then at some point push to a remote repository.